# Cannot get all data from php query

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make user notification for all user related updates. So as below I tried to make some sql query.

1. My 1st query get all follower id from follow table
2. 2nd query get all pages id that user liked from likes_user table
3. Based on above id's 3rd query try to find out new update on update table

Here my query cannot get my all follower ids to make 3rd query.

Here give my detail work:

```
$_GET['uid'] = $session->id;
// Find out all follower id by user
$rows=array();
$q = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT friend_two 
                        FROM follow 
                        WHERE  friend_one='".$_GET['uid']."'") 
                           or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    $rows[]["friend_two"] = $row['friend_two'];
}

// Find out all pages id liked by user
$rows=array();
$d = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT userid 
                        FROM likes_user 
                        WHERE ip='".$_GET['uid']."'") 
               or die(mysqli_error($dbh));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($d)) {
   $rows[]["userid"] = $row['userid'];
}


foreach($rows as $row) {
    $f2_id = $row['friend_two'];
    $pageid = $row['userid'];

    // echo all ids for test
    // **** cannot echo all $f2_id ids for test ****
    echo $f2_id;
    echo '<br>';
    echo $pageid;

    // Get all update ids
    $g = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT id 
                            FROM update WHERE 
                                `to_id`='".$myid."' 
                            AND `from_id`='".$f2_id."' 
                             OR `to_id`='".$pageid."' 
                             OR `from_id`='".$pageid."' 
                            AND `to_id`=''") 
                     or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($g)) {
        $ids[]= $rows['id'];
        // ids will go for next query
    } 
}
```

**UPDATE: Here now 3rd query got few ids twice or more**

Here problem on foreach .. replaced by

```
$q = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT friend_two FROM follow WHERE     friend_one='".$_GET['uid']."'") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
$f2_ids[] = $row['friend_two'];
}

$d = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT userid FROM likes_user WHERE ip='".$_GET['uid']."'") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($d)) {
$pg_ids[] = $row['userid'];
}

    foreach($f2_ids as $indx => $value) {
        //For test echo
        echo $f2_ids[$indx].$pg_ids[$indx];
        $g = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT id 
                        FROM update WHERE 
                            `to_id`='".$myid."' 
                        AND `from_id`='".$f2_ids[$indx]."' 
                         OR `to_id`='".$pg_ids[$indx]."' 
                         OR `from_id`='".$pg_ids[$indx]."' 
                        AND `to_id`=''") 
                 or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
        while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($g)) {
        $ids[]= $rows['id'];
        }
    }   
foreach ((array) $ids as $id ){
echo $id;
}
}
```

Comment: use parenthesis around `or` and `and`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the `$rows` array that you have built does not look like you think it does!

To see what you have actually produced in the `$rows` array add a `print_r()` just before you try and process the `$rows` array and your problem should become obvious.

Like this

```
print_r($rows);

foreach($rows as $row) {
    $f2_id = $row['friend_two'];
    $pageid = $row['userid'];
```

How you solve this I am not sure as I dont know your database!

Also there are many other issues in this script, too many to mention.